Help needed for creating a tagline for an awareness campaign
I'm designing some sensibilization posters for the 10th anniversary of the Ezidi genocide.
I'm struggling with finding the appropriate terms/words in German that combine brevity and impact with grammatical correctness and the more "verbose" nature of the German language. The last thing I want is for the message of the poster to be weakened by awkward, unusual or outright false word choice.
At its essence, the only message the poster needs to relay really is simply something along the lines of  "10th anniversary of the Yazidi genocide." In German I would write it as 10ter Jahrestag des Völkermordes an den Eziden, but for a max. A4 sized poster I'm trying to find ways to reduce this line as much as possible.
10. Jahrestag Völkermord an Eziden is the closest thing I can think of that doesn't sound "wrong" to German ears, but even then I'm not sure about it.
Additionally, based on conversations and interviews with survivors, the three main goals/wishes of the community are recognition/awareness (of the people's existence and of the genocide), justice and emancipation. This is a bit easier to translate in poster form and I opted for the following terms: Anerkennung, Gerechtigkeit, Emanzipation.
Even then though, I would really appreciate any feedback from advanced and native speakers on what sounds better in this specific context.

Do you mean Jesiden?
I know the transliteration into Latin script is not fixed but that spelling is what is used in German. So you should stick to that.

10ter Jahrestag des Völkermords an den Jesiden

That's not how we commonly write ordinals. Either write 10. or Zehnter. I recommend the latter:

Zehnter Jahrestag des Völkermords an den Jesiden

or you could write it

Zehn Jahre Völkermord an den Jesiden

as it's not a specific date anyways when that happened.

10. Jahrestag Völkermord an Eziden

No. That sounds super awkward.
— I recommend not to make A4 posters. They are too tiny. I make posters for hanging them at streetlights each year and A2 is the absolute minimum for that. For information boards in buildings, A3 is okay. A4 is insufficient for anything but handouts. —

Anerkennung, Gerechtigkeit, Emanzipation

Those aren't wrong but Emanzipation is commonly thought of being a slogan of feminism by Germans. Not as emancipation from unjust rule. So you should go with a synonym instead.
With Anerkennung it's unclear what should be acknowledged. I think it's about the genocide but that takes another thought. The more common thing people will think in that context is that Yazides want Anerkennung of their asylum claims. As that's the usual context of that word. And that has a bad rep. Sorry. You aren't at fault with that.
I recommend the slogan

Gerechtigkeit, Achtung, Selbstbestimmung

in that order. Gerechtigkeit is what you want for the genocide, Achtung so your people are acknowledged, and Selbstbestimmung as they want to govern themselves.
